# wrong output of a multiplier in IP catalogue

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, vivado, multiplier

I used a multiplier from IP catalogue in VIVADO.
[image]

```
--** = 12**
COMPONENT mult_gen_0
        PORT
            (
            CLK :                                   IN  STD_LOGIC;
            A :                                     IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((bits_t  - 1) DOWNTO 0);
            B :                                     IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((bits_t  - 1) DOWNTO 0);
            CE :                                    IN  STD_LOGIC;
            P :                                     OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((bits_t  - 1) DOWNTO 0)
            );
    END COMPONENT;
```

I have sent `000000000001` as `B` and `FF6` as `B`: have expected `FF6` ( B) as `P`.

**BUT**

The output is `FFF`( it was given as result of the simulation).

I believe the multiplier of IP catalogue works correctly... but I dont understand the output data.

Could someone explain why it happens?

**EDIT**
Thank you guys. I got the answer

Comment: have you considered latency? this is a clocked logic.

Comment: What was the output just before giving the input? Perhaps `FFF` is the default output.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, it is clk process

Comment: You should be careful working with signed numbers. If no negative numbers are used, settle with an unsigned multiplier.

Comment: @MituRaj I have negative numbers. Unfortunately I have to use signed.

Comment: Shoudn't you put the inputs into `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of 0xFFF on the output is correct.

Multiplying 0x001 and 0xFF6 as 12 Bit signed integers results in 0xFFFFF6.
Now you specify the output width as 12 Bit - and the uppermost 12 Bit of the result are 0xFFF.

Comment: Why do we take the uppermost bit? Can i drop off the MSB side bits?

Comment: It't what you configured the IP block for. Sure, you can use only the lower 12 bits if you are sure your result will always be with -2048..2047.